# <input> end tag unable to parse

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to run below code. seems input tag end tag has been remove by jsoup. if you look out of html, input tag is coming like  `<input type="checkbox" readonly checked>` it doesn't have end tag. It should come like `<input type="checkbox" readonly checked/>`.

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
  + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p> <input type="checkbox"  readonly="readonly" checked="checked"/> </body></html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

System.out.println(doc.html());
```

Comment: Why do you want to self-close the tag? The output is perfectly valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup is parsing as HTML5. There is no need for endtags in self closing tags in HTML5. You can configure jsoup to parse as XML if you want self closing tags:

`doc.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml);`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of double quotation marks use the single quotes in html

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
  + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p> <input type='checkbox'  readonly='readonly' checked='checked'/> </body></html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

System.out.println(doc.html());
```

Comment: if you are in a html page with content the other tags will be ignored, you should return this all only if the page is blank